# How to split string in correct way?

Tags: javascript

For example, I have this string:

`a = "Hello, @USER_ID:1@, how are you?"`

I need to turn this string into array of words:

`["Hello, ", "@USER_ID:1@", ", how are you?"]`

I've tried this piece of code:

`a.split(/\@USER_ID:([0-9]+)\@/)`

But it returns this:

`["Hello, ", "1", ", how are you?"]`

What is the proper way to split this string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use a regular expression as `split` argument, the capture group (matched by what is between parentheses) is also returned in the result. So you should just make that capture group the whole expression:

```
 a.split(/(\@USER_ID:[0-9]+\@)/)
```

Note that the regular expression can be shortened to:

```
 a.split(/(@USER_ID:\d+@)/)
```

Comment: OP: And for what it's worth, there's no need to escape `@` in regular expressions.